# How to simulate an <a> tag with class and data-type after .on("click".... in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, lightbox

I'm trying to use the [venobox lightbox](https://github.com/nicolafranchini/VenoBox) to allow a user to select a user-generated item on a page and edit its contents.  The u-g item has a button made with jQueryUI:

```
<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span>
```

I want to click on that and have an edit form appear in a venobox lightbox.  Venobox offers an iframe option that should do nicely.  To call venobox I need to do something like

```
<a class='venobox_custom' data-type='iframe' href='http://www.sample.com/editform.html'>open iFrame</a>
```

so I can't just use `"window.location = url"`  How can I specify the class and data-type with the url?

Without much hope, I tried inserting the full anchor text inside the span, but nothing shows up to click and clicking on the button does not invoke venobox.

I've got the `.on("click")` logic working, just not calling **venobox**.

***Edited, July 27***

I've put the code in cut-down form and runable here: 
http://www.informationtamers.com/venoboxtest/index.html

I've tried both the iframe and inline options, and this code demonstrates them both, but they won't invoke Venobox.  There's a hard link as well that shows Venobox working but not in the way I need to use it.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <!-- venobox is a jquery lightbox plugin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="venobox/venobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <title>UG list</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I've removed as much of the functionality as I can, like getting users' previously-added content from a JSON file, saving it after changes, sanitizing user content, and so on.</p>
        <p>First, add a line by pressing Add.<br/>
        While experimenting with venobox, I've made that generate two lines:
        The first uses venobox's 'inline' option, the second, its 'iframe' option.</p>

        <div id="inputs" class="textIn">
            <form name="checkListForm" >
                <input type="text" id="textEntry" name="userEntry" style="width: 99%; height:25px"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="controls" style="width: 100%">
            <div id="buttonItem">Add</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">

        </ul>
        <p>Once you've added a line, click the blue pencil button that appears on the right of the first line.  This doesn't appear to invoke venobox, although console.log entries show that it's passing through the on-click code.</p>
        <p>Then click the blue pencil button that appears on the right of the second line. This loads editform.html into the browser window directly instead of showing it in a lightbox.  It appears to be treating it as a normal hyperlink.</p>
        <p>The behavior I'm trying to get can be seen if you click this link (uses the 'inline' option):<br/> 
        <center><a class='venobox_custom' data-type='inline' href='#lightboxform'><b>open inline form in lightbox</b></a></center><br/>


        <div id="lightboxform" style="display:none">
            <div class="textIn">
                <form name="editForm" >
                    <input type="text" id="textEdit" name="userEdit" style="width: 99%; height:25px"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="controls" style="width: 100%">
                <div id="buttonItem">Save changes</div>
            </div>


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Add venobox (a jquery lightbox plugin) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>

        <script>

// ƒ to MOVE new user input to a <li> item
            function sendLineToDOM (lineType) {
                var toAdd = $('input[name=userEntry]').val();
                if (toAdd == null || toAdd == "") {
                    console.log('empty');
                }
                else {
                    // two lines generated here while experimenting with venobox
                    // this uses venobox's 'inline' option
                    $('.list').prepend("<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + "iframe: " + toAdd + "<span class='edit'><a class='venobox_custom' data-type='iframe' href='editform.html'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></a></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>");
                    // this uses venobox's 'iframe' option
                    $('.list').prepend("<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + "inline: " + toAdd + "<span class='edit'><a class='venobox_custom' data-type='inline' href='#lightboxform'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></a></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>");
                    // empty text input field once data consumed
                    $('#textEntry').val("");
                    }
                }

// Substantive START
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#textEntry').val("Some text or other here.");

console.log('Initialize lightbox plugin');
/* default settings */
                $('.venobox').venobox(); 

                /* open content with custom settings */
                $('.venobox_custom').venobox({
                    framewidth: '300px',
                    frameheight: '250px',
                    border: '6px',
                    bordercolor: '#ba7c36',
                    numeratio: true,
                    infinigall: true
                });

                /* auto-open #firstlink on page load */
                $("#firstlink").venobox().trigger('click');

                // Enable  DRAG  of list items vertically to re-order them
                $(".list").sortable( {  
                    handle: ".handle"
                });

                // DELETE  a line when its red-button trash symbol is clicked on
                $(document).on("click", ".delete", function () 
                {
                    var whichOne = Math.floor( $("span").index(this) / 7 );
                    $( "ul li" ).eq( whichOne ).remove();
                });

                // EDIT  a line when its blue-button pencil symbol is clicked on
                $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () 
                {
console.log('Click on edit button detected for line #:');
                    var whichOne = Math.floor( $("span").index(this) / 7 );
console.log(whichOne);
                    var input = $( 'input[name=userEntry]' );
                    var extractedText = $( "ul li" ).eq(whichOne).text();
// The following was an initial form for user text editing, but for the planned functionality, I want to show the lightbox instead.
                    $('#textEdit').val( extractedText );
console.log(extractedText);
                });

                /* Add a line with text box contents as ACTION text when Action button pressed*/
                $('#buttonItem').click(function () {
console.log('Add Action text on button press');
                    sendLineToDOM ('item');
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why would you need to do `.on('click')` or `window.location`, all of that should be handled by the library. Can you post more code? A JSFiddle?

Comment: @MAtt As far as I can see, the only way venobox can be invoked is by the &lt;a class= etc. statement.  The library doesn't seem to offer any alternative way.  I need to use on click to get the user's existing text before I display the iframe presenting that text to be edited.

I'll produce an essential's-only piece of code shortly.

Comment: So you're trying to pass some input from a form field into the modal window? Some code definitely would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, code now included and a live running version given at the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Niklas gave me a working answer (and improved my code), but at that stage, I hadn't worked out how I was going to pass the data to be edited to the lightbox form.  After much trial and searching, I found that this was either not possible or not not withing my grasp, so I'm revisiting this with an eventual full solution in case anyone else is looking for a way to allow users to edit text they've input previously in a lightbox and save it back to the page. (Note that this doesn't include sanitizing user content which would obviously be necessary.)

The problem was that clicking on the blue edit button immediately launched the Venobox lightbox - there was no opportunity to load the existing data to the input field. I could find no information in the Venobox documentation about how that might be done. In my project there will be many lines of user-entered data, and each has an associated edit button but once the edit lightbox is triggered, it's too late to get the data.

The solution was a different lightbox jquery plugin: Colorbox.  http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

This is well-documented.  As well as working with hyperlinks, it has a way of calling Colorbox directly, so that I can trigger editing with 'on click', set up the input form data chosen, and jump into colorbox, and do all the other actions needed.

The code is below, but again, I've put a runable example on line here:
http://www.informationtamers.com/colorboxtest/index.html

I've removed the venobox online code mentioned in my question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <!-- colorbox is a jquery lightbox plugin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <title>UG list</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I've removed much of the functionality, like getting users' previously-added content from a JSON file, saving it after changes, sanitizing user content, and so on.</p>
        <p>First, press Add to generate a line, then key in one or two more lines.</p>

        <div id="inputs" class="textIn">
            <form name="checkListForm" >
                <input type="text" id="textEntry" name="userEntry" style="width: 99%; height:25px"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="controls" style="width: 100%">
            <div id="buttonItem">Add</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">

        </ul>
        <p>Next, press one of the blue pencil buttons, change the text presented in the lightbox input form, and press Save changes.</p>


        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="lightboxform">
                <div class="textIn" >
                    <form name="editForm" >
                        <input type="text" id="textEdit" name="userEdit" style="width: 99%; height:25px"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="controls" style="width: 100%">
                    <center><div id="buttonSaveChange">Save changes</div></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script> <!-- colorbox is a jquery lightbox plugin -->


        <script>

// ƒ to add new user input to a <li> item
            function sendLineToDOM (lineType, lineText) {
                var toAdd = lineText;
                if (lineText == null || lineText == "") {
                    console.log('empty');
                }
                else {
                    var inlineRow = "<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + lineText + "<span class='edit'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>";
                    $('.list').prepend(inlineRow);
                    // empty text input field once data consumed
                    $('#textEntry').val("");
                }
            }

// ƒ to move edited input to appropriate <li> item
            function returnLineToDOM (lineType, lineText) {
                if (lineText == null || lineText == "") {
                    console.log('empty');
                }
                else {
                    var inlineRow = "<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + lineText + "<span class='edit'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>";
                    // replace original line
                    $( "ul li" ).eq( whichOne ).replaceWith( inlineRow );

                    // empty text input field once data consumed
console.log('data consumed, empty text input field');
                    $('#textEdit').val("");
                }
            }

// Substantive START
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#textEntry').val("Some text or other here.");

                /* Define global variables */
                window.whichOne = 0; // global variable indicating which line selected for edit
                window.extractedText = ""; // global variable to hold user text selected for edit

                // Enable  DRAG  of list items vertically to re-order them
                $(".list").sortable( {  
                    handle: ".handle"
                });

                // DELETE  a line when its red-button trash symbol is clicked on
                $(document).on("click", ".delete", function () 
                {
                    var whichOne = Math.floor( $("span").index(this) / 7 );
                    $( "ul li" ).eq( whichOne ).remove();
                });

                // EDIT  a line when its blue-button pencil symbol is clicked on
                $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () 
                {
console.log('Click on edit button detected for line #:');
                    var whichOne = Math.floor( $("span").index(this) / 7 );
console.log(whichOne);
                    var input = $( 'input[name=userEntry]' );
                    var extractedText = $( "ul li" ).eq(whichOne).text();
                    $('#textEdit').val( extractedText );
console.log(extractedText);
                });

                // Add line w.text box contents as action text when Action button pressed
                $('#buttonItem').click(function () {
console.log('Add Action text on button press');
                    sendLineToDOM ('item', $('input[name=userEntry]').val());
                });

                // EDIT  a line when its blue-button pencil symbol is clicked on
                $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
console.log('Edit a line');
                    // The divisor in the next expression is the number of <span>s before the 
                    // clicked one in the <li> lines constructed in sendLineToDOM(). This 
                    // works out which blue button has been pressed, and therefore which 
                    // <li> item to edit.
                    whichOne = Math.floor( $("span").index(this) / 7 );
console.log(whichOne);
                    var input = $( 'input[name=userEntry]' );
                    extractedText = $( "ul li" ).eq(whichOne).text();
console.log('extracted:' + extractedText );
                    $('#textEdit').val( extractedText );
                    $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#lightboxform", width:"80%", height:"25%"});
                });

/* RELOAD edited line on click */
                // Get the edited user input and replace the old entry with it.
                $('#buttonSaveChange').click(function () {
console.log('Replace old entry on button press');
//                  Save edited text!!!!
                    returnLineToDOM ('item', $('input[name=userEdit]').val());
                    $.colorbox.close()
                }); 

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add new elements dynamically to the DOM tree, these new elements don't automagically get effected by already initialized code. In your case you'll have to initialize the venobox on each new link after it's added. Try this:

```
    function sendLineToDOM (lineType) {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=userEntry]').val();
        if (toAdd == null || toAdd == "") {
            console.log('empty');
        }
        else {
            // two lines generated here while experimenting with venobox
            // this uses venobox's 'iframe' option
            var iframeRow = $("<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + "iframe: " + toAdd + "<span class='edit'><a class='venobox_custom' data-type='iframe' href='editform.html'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></a></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>"),
                iframeLink = iframeRow.find('a');
            $('.list').prepend(iframeRow);
            // this uses venobox's 'inline' option
            var inlineRow = $("<li><span class='" + lineType + "'><span class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span></span>" + "inline: " + toAdd + "<span class='edit'><a class='venobox_custom' data-type='inline' href='#lightboxform'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></a></span><span class='delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></span></span></li>"),
                inlineLink = inlineRow.find('a');
            $('.list').prepend(inlineRow);
            // empty text input field once data consumed
            $('#textEntry').val("");
            iframeLink.venobox();
            inlineLink.venobox();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been using on click because when the user clicks on the jQueryUI button, I need to grab the existing user-generated text and populate the iframe form with it, before the iframe is shown.  I tried your suggestion, but it's as before - I can see that the click is detected, but the lightbox doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks @Niklas.  Given that the code occurs for each line of input the user adds, as you'll see if you run the example (details edited into the original question), I can't see how to add the mousedown code that you kindly suggested, as pressing the edit (blue pencil) button triggers venobox, and only then do I know which text to work on - there will be multiple lines, and only one will be edited at one time.

Comment: Yes, just saw your example and I think I know what the problem is, I didn't understand that the links being clicked was added dynamically to the page using javascript/jQuery. This changes things. I guess you only initializes the venobox plugin at page load. Perhaps only including the .js file in your page? This will make the venobox plugin find all the current links, new links added dynamically will not automagically get found by the venobox plugin. You'll need to reinitialize the venobox plugin after each new row i added. Hope this helps!

Comment: If this fixes your problems, please let me know and I'll update my actual answer!

Comment: Please see my updated answer for an example I think might work.

Comment: that was it ... I would never have worked that out myself.  I greatly appreciate your help and will mark this answered once you've edited.

Comment: Were you going to remove the mousedown code from the answer? Because I couldn't implement that, but just followed your suggestion of reinitializing the venebox plugin each time some entries on the page were changed.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. Thought that worked for you as well, but see now that you just understood my thinking. Old answer removed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the intention was to obtain control of the flow once the iframe is opened up.

We can do that by passing a callback function inside the venobox options like below.

```
    // Venobox setup
$('.venobox_custom').venobox({
    // framewidth : '400px',                            // default: ''
    frameheight : '110vh',                            // default: ''
    border      : '10px',                             // default: '0'
    bgcolor     : '#96c9db',                          // default: '#fff'
    titleattr   : 'data-title',                       // default: 'title'
    titleColer  : '#fff',
    titleBackground: '#1bbd36',
    cb_post_open  : function(){
        console.log('POST OPEN');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution more easy is inicialitate the plugin of VENOBOX after reload the new elements in your component. You can test this:

```
//when load the web site 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.venobox').venobox(); 
}); 

//When you replace or add new elements in your component 
$('.venobox').venobox(); //Note: this goes in the end after create elements
```